# How to use a cygwin command line and clip.exe got get command's output into the clipboard?

Tags: windows, cygwin, autohotkey, clipboard

I am trying to get output from the [hunspell hyphenation utility (for en_US)](https://github.com/hunspell/hyphen) into the clipboard, using AutoHotKey.

Since I have installed Cygwin anyway (the 64-bit version, if it matters), I first have cloned the hunspell hyphenation git repository (for en_US) and have compiled and installed it in Cygwin. From within Cygwin, it is working as expected:

```
peter@odo /home/git/hyphen
$ echo example | ./example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin
ex=am=ple
```

As the next step, I have worked out some variants of command lines which could be used not from within Cygwin directly, but from the Windows command interpreter to get the same result. Among others, the following worked:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\git\hyphen>%comspec% /c (c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin")
ex=am=ple

C:\cygwin64\home\git\hyphen>%comspec% /c c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin"
ex=am=ple

C:\cygwin64\home\git\hyphen>c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin"
ex=am=ple

C:\cygwin64\home\git\hyphen>c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c -- "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin"
ex=am=ple
```

From within the Windows command interpreter, it is very easy to get the output into the clipboard (clip.exe is a part of Windows in recent Windows versions), for example:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\git\hyphen>c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin" | clip
```

Now I thought I just had to transfer this to an AutoHotKey script and to connect it to a shortcut (in my case, F12); the relevant part of the AutoHotKey script looked like

```
F12::
RunWait, %ComSpec% /c c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin" | clip
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. When I pressed F12, a Windows opened for a very short time, but obviously nothing was copied to the clipboard. I first thought that I would need some more quoting or that I should leave away the `%compec%` thing, so I have tried a whole lot of other variants, for example

```
F12::
RunWait, c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin" | clip

F12::
RunWait, %ComSpec% /c "c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c ""echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin""" | clip

F12::
RunWait, %ComSpec% /c c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin" | clip
```

and so on, but without success.

I am not even sure at which stage it fails; it may be the quotes, or it may be that clip.exe does not work as expected when called from within AutoHotKey.

I even have seen an example where they were using `mintty.exe` and were claiming that without it there would be no standard input / output, so we would need it. The respective AHK script entry was something like that:

```
F12::
RunWait, c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -e /usr/bin/bash.exe -lic "echo example | /home/git/hyphen/example hyph_en_US.dic /dev/stdin" | clip
```

Needless to say that this also didn't work. i.e. didn't change the clipboard's contents.

Of course, I am aware that I would have to replace `echo example` by something else for that script to be useful (actually, I'd like to feed the current clipboard's content to the script). But in any case, the first step would be to make the current script (with the hard-coded input `"example"`) work.

Could somebody please tell me how I could change the AutoHotKey script to make it work?

By the way, clip.exe in general seems to work from within AutoHotKey. As a very simple example,

```
F12::
RunWait %ComSpec% /c "ipconfig" | clip
```

works as expected.

I think I have read some dozens of similar threads and questions, but none of them involved both Cygwin and the clipboard, and although I have tried to learn as much as possible from these other sources, I could not find a solution myself.

[Not really relevant for the question, but just in case somebody is wondering why I am trying to involve `bash.exe` at all]:

The program `example` can be run from within the Windows command interpreter, but it expects a **file** (containing a word list) as last parameter. During several hours of research, I haven't found out how to use `stdin` as a file in the Windows command interpreter. I could solve that problem by redirecting the input in a temporary file and then use that file as input, but this would be very ugly.

By letting Cygwin's `bash.exe` do the work, this problem is easily avoided (hoping that Cygwin in turn does not implement `/dev/stdin` using a temporary file).

Comment: Have you tried with `getclip.exe`  and `putclip.exe` of `cygutils` package ?

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I already had found them, but they seem obsolete now. Instead, I have tried to use /dev/clipboard. But that didn't help either.

Comment: Obsolete ? They works well in my simple test. `man man | putclip` and I have the manual in the windows clipboard.

Comment: I don't doubt they are working correctly, but from reading an article on another website (just can't remember exactly where it was) I have got the impression that the special device `/dev/clipboard` which Cygwin provides should be preferred over `putclip` and `getclip`. Furthermore, I believe I remember that the latter both have issues with UTF8-encoded texts or maybe even with Unicode characters in general.

Comment: `man man | u2d > /dev/clipboard` manages better the UTF8 conversion